ERC-20 Token appears on Sepolia network but not on Polygon network
I have attempted to create an ERC-20 token, and deployed the contract on both Sepolia and Polygon, it appeared successfully as a token on Sepolia network but not on Polygon.
etherscan
polygonscan
contracts/ploytoken.sol
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity <=0.8.19;
import "solmate/src/tokens/ERC20.sol";

contract PolyToken is ERC20 {
    address public owner;

    constructor() ERC20("Poly Token", "Poly", 18) {
        owner = msg.sender;
        _mint(msg.sender, 100000 * 10**18);
    }

    function mint(address to, uint256 amount) external {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Only owner can mint");
        _mint(to, amount);
    }
}

deploy/01-deploy-polytoken.sol
const { network, getNamedAccounts } = require("hardhat");

module.exports = async (hre) => {
    const { deploy } = deployments;
    const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts();
    const chainId = network.config.chainId;
    
    const polyToken = await deploy("PolyToken", {
        from: deployer,
        log: true,
        args: [],
        waitConfirmations: chainId == 31337 ? 1 : 6,
    });
};

module.exports.tags = ["all", "polyToken"];

